# Remove does not work for select list

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code to add items to a select box. Before adding new item to the select list, I need to clear the existing items. I used `remove` method. But it is not removing the items. What need to be changed for this to work?

**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnProgramDescriptionMagnifingLens").click(function () {
            alert('Clicked');
            var costPageDisplayText = 'A';

            //REMOVE
            var id = $('mtxtProgramDescription option').remove();

            //ADD
            var o = new Option(costPageDisplayText, 'B');
            $(o).html(costPageDisplayText);
            $("#mtxtProgramDescription").append(o);

        });


    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .floaterleft {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

      <div class="floaterleft">

        <div class="descriptionLeft">
            <label for="Program___Description">Program / Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="controlLeft">
            <div class="partialFirstLine">
                <div class="headerTextBox">
                    <input id="txtProgramDescription" class="searchTextbox" id="Program" name="Program" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="Magenifyingbtn">
                    <img src="/Images/Lens2.png" id="btnProgramDescriptionMagnifingLens" class="Magenifyingbtn" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="partialSecondLine">
                <select id="mtxtProgramDescription" name="mtxtProgramDescription" multiple="multiple" class="multiSelectCommon"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="floaterleft">
        <div class="partLeft">

            <div class="subLeft">
                <div class="headerLabelPrintItem">
                    <label for="Print_Item">Print Item</label>
                </div>
                <div class="headerTextBoxPrintItem">
                    <select id="ddlPrintItem" name="ddlPrintItem">
                        <option value="Select">-- Select --</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="subLeft">
                <div class="headerLabelPrintItem">
                    <label for="Order_Type">Order Type</label>
                </div>
                <div class="headerTextBoxPrintItem">
                    <select id="Select1" name="ddlPrintItem">
                        <option value="Select">-- Select --</option>
                        <option value="Direct">Direct</option>
                        <option value="Indirect">Indirect</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the ID selector, change:

```
$('mtxtProgramDescription option')
```

to

```
$('#mtxtProgramDescription option')
//^^^ note the #
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it like this:

```
Change this :
var id = $('mtxtProgramDescription option').remove();
To:
$('#mtxtProgramDescription option').remove();
```